# SQL select duplicates on specific day

Tags: sql, select, plsql, duplicates

I'm trying to find duplicate entries which occurred on the same day. I have a database table which basically consists only from ID, USERNAME and DATE_CREATED.

I need a select which does roughly this:

```
SELECT USERNAME,DATE_CREATED 
FROM THE_TABLE WHERE {more than one USERNAME exists on date TRUNC(DATE_CREATED)}
```

Is it possible to do it without creating a procedure only by SELECT? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return the full date in the output.

```
SELECT 
      USERNAME
    , DATE_CREATED 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
       USERNAME
    ,  DATE_CREATED
    ,  COUNT( *) over ( PARTITION by USERNAME, TRUNC( DATE_CREATED, 'DD') ) cnt
  FROM THE_TABLE
)
WHERE cnt > 1
;
```

Comment: Good idea. I guess you have seen it before. :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT  USERNAME, TRUNC(DATE_CREATED)
FROM    THE_TABLE
GROUP   BY
        USERNAME, TRUNC(DATE_CREATED)
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Example:

```
SELECT  USERNAME, TRUNC(DATE_CREATED)
FROM    
(
        SELECT  'a' username, sysdate date_created from dual union all
        SELECT  'a' username, sysdate date_created from dual union all
        SELECT  'b' username, sysdate date_created from dual union all
        SELECT  'b' username, sysdate date_created from dual
)
GROUP   BY
        USERNAME, TRUNC(DATE_CREATED)
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1;
/*
a   2013-06-18 00:00:00
b   2013-06-18 00:00:00
*/
```

To get the full date in the output it is slightly complicated:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        username
,       date_created
FROM    the_table ot
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    the_table it
            WHERE   TRUNC(ot.date_created) = TRUNC(it.date_created)
            AND     ot.username            = it.username
            GROUP   BY
                    USERNAME, TRUNC(DATE_CREATED)
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
;
/*
a   2013-06-18 12:48:40
b   2013-06-18 12:48:40
*/
```

Table has to be accessed twice + DISTINCT keyword is required. Yes, the performance can decrease.

Comment: Yes, this is almost entirely what I need, except for that I need the full date in the output, not just the truncated one. Can you edit that one thing please? Thanks!

Comment: take a look at schurik's answer it looks quite nice I wouldn't be surprised if it is better.

Comment: Yes, his answer is clearer to me but I am really thankful for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT USERNAME, trunc(DATE_CREATED)
FROM THE_TABLE 
group by Username,TRUNC(DATE_CREATED)
having count(1) > 1
```

Comment: This doesn't output the whole date. See shurik's answer. But +1, hence I have specified that later ;)

Comment: Yup, for getting the full row, you must use subselects as shown in the other answer from the_slk

Answer (score 0):

Use [Having](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

```
select USERNAME, DATE_CREATED 
from test
group by USERNAME, DATE_CREATED 
Having COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: count(1) has no advantage over count(*), and is non-standard syntax